# What means "*" after "@" in solr query

Tags: solr

I have the query: `http://localhost:8983/solr/user/select?q=username%3Auser%40site*&wt=json&indent=true` for `username:user@site*` but the number of results is 0. If I remove `*` number of results will be correct. And if I use query `username:user` and `username:user*` the results will be same.

What's happening when I use `*` after `@` in queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing happening is that `*` makes the query a wildcard query. When the query has a wildcard, no analysis (well, not exactly correct, as certain multitermaware filters still are applied) takes place. So if your field is split on `@` for example into `user` and `site` tokens when indexing, that same split does not happen when you're querying.

So Lucene tries to find a token that starts with `user@site`, but since the only tokens available in the index is `user` and `site`, none of these matches. If you tried searching `user*`, you'd probably get a hit.

You can use the Analysis page under Solr's Admin to see how a field is being processed for your input.

Comment: You can fix this by changing your schema.xml and use the `KeywordTokenizerFactory` for `username`. Then you can just use the `@` for querying.

Comment: .. given that the goal is to query by the prefix of the user@domain string, using a KeywordTokenizer should work - you can also use a separate field for this, and use a copyField instruction to copy content into that one for querying as a prefix.